# Missing Query rows

Tags: php

why is my query just showing one result?? it should've showing 5 or more result base on my database

here's the link :

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dummy") or die(mysql_error());

// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM resdummy where am='hendri_humaedi'")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
```

Comment: you need to loop the fetching function in a `while`

Comment: considering your criteria matches more than one record, I am posting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should populate all records using a loop:

```
// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM resdummy where am='hendri_humaedi'")
                or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
 print_r($row); //<-- just to show you record details
}
```

> Use of `mysql_*` functions is highly discouraged. Use `mysqli_*`
>   functions or PDO.

Comment: agreed. `mysql_*` is depricated in later versions